# MongoDB/Mongoose query returns []: Importing (but not using) Bluebird fixes it

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, bluebird

I have a MERN stack web app, and when I did a basic GET request w/ Axios to `find()` all entries in a MongoDB instance (via router, controller, models), it returned an empty array. Loading localhost:3000/nibs in a browser, doing a GET request w/ Postman to localhost:3000/nibs, and the logic in my server models all returned `[]`, despite there being data in the specified db and collection, which I verified via Mongo shell and MongoDB Compass.

I tried everything I could think of to fix this (syntax errors, the Mongoose Collection -> collections quirk, etc.) and only resolved it when I installed and required Bluebird. The weird thing is, requiring Bluebird at the top of db/index.js fixes the problem, even if I don't `promisifyAll()` Mongoose or use any promisified `Async` functions in the code.

Can anyone explain why? The code below works, but if I remove the Bluebird import, it breaks and I don't understand why. It seems like I'm using 'normal' (i.e. non-Bluebird) syntax but the Bluebird import is necessary to make it work...

**Main.jsx**

```
class Main extends Component { 
  // ...
  getNibs() {
    axios.get('/nibs')
      .then(({ data }) => {
        console.log(`* Main | getNibs | data:`, data)
        this.setState({
          NIBs: data
        })
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.error(`! Main | getNibs | err:`, err)
      })
  }
  // ...
}
```

Main.jsx -> server/index.js -> server/router.js -> server/controllers.js -> server/models.js

**models.js**

```
const db = require('../db/index')

const read = (input) => {
  console.log(`* models | read | input:`, input)
  if (input === 'nibs') {
    console.log(`* models.read called on 'nibs'`)
    return db.nibs.find() // (originally tried w/ and w/o .exec(), w/ no luck
  }
}

module.exports = {
  read,
  // ...
}
```

**db/index.js**

```
const Promise = require('bluebird') // breaks w/o this
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

// ...

const nibSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  category: { type: String, required: true },
  date: { type: Date, required: true , default: Date.now() },
  source: { type: String, required: true },
  title: { type: String, required: true },
  body: { type: String, required: true },
  tags: { type: Array, required: false }
})

const nibs = mongoose.model('nibs', nibSchema)

module.exports = {
  nibs
}
```

Comment: What is the error that you see? Please paste it

Comment: @KashinathPatekar, there wasn't an error, it was just returning an empty array even though there was data in the database. I uncommented the line requiring Bluebird and it no longer creates the error, so I'm not sure what was happening.