# Mongoose.model.find() always returns empty array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Im building a web app backend server using **node.js**, with the help of the **mongoose** and **express** libraries. my code listnes on route "/" using **express.Router().get()**, and when a "get request" was recived it fetches the data from the mongodb collection using **mongoose.model.find()** and sends the data back.

the problem is that no matter what i have tried, **mongoose.model.find()** returns an empty array...

**this is the code of express.Router().get():**

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

const AttackPattern = require("../models/attack_pattern"); //the model

router.get("/", (req, res) => {
  AttackPattern.find({}, function (err, docs) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("error!"); //there was an error...
    } else {
      console.log(docs); //fetch succeful
      res.status(200).send(docs);
    }
  });
});
```

**and this is the code of the model:**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const attackPatternSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  _id: String,
  name: String,
  description: String,
  x_mitre_platforms: [String],
  x_mitre_detection: String,
  phase_name: String,
});

module.exports = mongoose.model(
  "AttackPattern",
  attackPatternSchema,
  "attack_pattern"
);
```

i have already looked at [Model.find() returns empty in mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18628656/model-find-returns-empty-in-mongoose) and [Mongoose always returning an empty array NodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14183611/mongoose-always-returning-an-empty-array-nodejs) but found no luck...

**IMPORTANT TO KNOW:**

1. The name of the collection is "attack_pattern" matching the third parameter of mongoose.model().
2. The Schema's fields names and types match the documents of the collection's fields names and types.
3. The connection to the mongodb cluster is succesful (established in another file).
4. The field _id is of type string, not ObjectId (the documents _id field still have a unique value, but its not autoly generated).

help will be appreciated :)

Comment: Did you have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61853064)? The OP suggests adding `const Promise = require('bluebird')` would somehow confusingly solve it

Comment: `module.exports = mongoose.model('attackPattern', attackPatternSchema)` try this

Comment: unfortunalety both solutions did'ny fixed the problem... any other suggestions?

Comment: Is it possible that you have connected to a different database? Have you tried inserting new documents and `.find()` it in the same flow?

Comment: thanks @thammada that was it! apperantly i was connected to an unexisting db called "test", after i changed it to the correct db it was all good :)

Comment: @איילהיינריך Feel free to post as an answer and accept it, others might benefit from this.

Answer (score 0):

In your model delete param attack_pattern

```
module.exports = mongoose.model(
  "AttackPattern",
  attackPatternSchema
);
```

or

when you create your model, change mongoose.model by new Schema and declare `_id` attribute like:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var attackPatternSchema = new Schema({
    _id: { type: Schema.ObjectId, auto: true },
    // others attributes
})
```

Comment: unfortunalety it did'nt fixed the problem... any other suggestions?

Comment: @איילהיינריך I changed my answer, cheeck it

Comment: @איילהיינריך if you desired declared `_id` must be `new Schema({ _id: { type: Schema.ObjectId, auto: true }})`, I changed again my answer, cheeck it.

Comment: did'nt worked eather... did'nt mentioned it but field _id is of type string, not objectId (the documents _id field still have a unique value, but its not autoly generated).

Comment: ok, try change your `_id` to other name like `idAttack` or just `id`, that can be error, read https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/1285

Comment: now im really frustrated... i've changed the document's of the collection to have an auto-selected _id field of type ObjectId, and added field id of type string (holds the values of field _id from the old docs), changed the schema correspondingly and still no success :(

Comment: jaja take it easy my friend, put some logs error to can help you